# login redirection

Tags: 7, users, javascript, redirection

I'm using a modal form module to display a modal login window, so far so good, but when I attempt to let it redirect on the current page that the user is displaying it redirect me to a not existing page.
For example, when I do login it redirect me to www.mydomain/m instead of www.mydomain/current-page

What I've already tried is to set as a redirect  in the login destination module, but it won't work (It redirect me to the the page above). 
I've tried as well to build a rule that will redirect me to [site:current-page:url], but the result is http://www.mydomain/modal/ajax/login, it seems to bring the link of the page that make the access.

The question is, how I can get the current page during the redirect? Do I need to get the previous page somehow?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The login toboggan module will probably help for this redirection issue.
- Install and enable the module : https://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan 
- Go in the admin interface and choose the login destination : admin/config/system/logintoboggan if you want to override the default behavior which is the destination parameter I think, so the current page.

Comment: Thanks, Tritof for the suggestion, btw the solution was more easier than this, after disabling login destination module via drush, I was having just the rule active for the redirect and it started to work well. So just setting the rule makes the work. Many thanks :)

Comment: you're welcome, also because you partially let me solve the problem. If you didn't suggest to me that solution I would never disable login destination module lol.

Comment: Hello Gianni. I am facing the same problem.I am redirecting to http://www.mydomain/modal/ajax/login, As per you suggestion disabling the login destination,But I do not have login destination  installed in my site.
Can you please guide me how can I come out of this issue?
Thanks in Advance.